# Storing the each binary bit in differnt array index

Tags: c#, image-processing

For my off line signature verification project i am using the Euler vector as a topological features.

If i name for 8 bit binary number as (b7,b6,b5,b4,...,b0). how to store each each bit b7,b6 etc in separately?

For example if the 8 bit binary value is 10101010. array a[0] should store 0,a[1] should store 1 ,a[7] should store most significant bit i.e 1. I am beginner and it is one of our group project that I need to submit to my teacher.

Comment: I suggest you research "bitwise operations". In particular, you're likely to want the `<<` and `&` operators.

Comment: Would the `BitArray` class be of any use to you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there is any online materials  that will help me better to understand ?

Comment: Absolutely - that's why I suggested researching "bitwise operations". (Or "bitwise operators" - either will work.)